# Snowflake SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 55 N"'TEST'"

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just started using SnowFlake and experiencing issues making a basic snowflake insert builder procedure where if the insert parameter on call is process with a "''" it will error. In the example below.
`SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 55 N"'TEST'"`

The procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "INSERTTABLECOLUMNS"("TABLENAME" VARCHAR(250), "INSERTCOLUMNS" VARCHAR(250), "INSERTVALUES" VARCHAR(250))
    RETURNS VARCHAR()
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
    var command = "INSERT INTO "+TABLENAME+" ("+INSERTCOLUMNS+") VALUES ("+INSERTVALUES+")";  
    var cmd1_dict = {sqlText: command};  
    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd1_dict);  
    var rs = stmt.execute();  
    return "Works";  
    $$;
```

The Call

```
call DEMO.PUBLIC.INSERTTABLECOLUMNS('TESTBEGIN','NAME',"'TEST'")
call DEMO.PUBLIC.INSERTTABLECOLUMNS('TESTBEGIN','NAME,COLUMN2',"'TEST',2")
```

Comment: Which of the 2 calls is generating the error, or are both erroring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the double quotes are mostly used for signifying object names when you have abnormal characters in your table/column names, for example.

I think what you want is to escape your `'` characters. You can do that either with a double apostrophe: `''` or a backslash: `\'` .

```sql
call DEMO.PUBLIC.INSERTTABLECOLUMNS('TESTBEGIN','NAME','''TEST''')
call DEMO.PUBLIC.INSERTTABLECOLUMNS('TESTBEGIN','NAME,COLUMN2','''TEST'',2')
```

Or

```sql
call DEMO.PUBLIC.INSERTTABLECOLUMNS('TESTBEGIN','NAME','\'TEST\'')
call DEMO.PUBLIC.INSERTTABLECOLUMNS('TESTBEGIN','NAME,COLUMN2','\'TEST\',2')
```

Comment: Thanks both are valid.